# How do I commit code blocks in my git commit messages

Tags: bash, git

### My problem

While writing a commit message, I tried to use the " ` " mark to format the message with code.
This is my commit message:

```bash
git commit -am"style(Nav.tsx): adheres to eslint rules

line 92 and 122: add `@returns` in docstrings"
```

After I execute the command, I get this

```bash
bash: @returns: command not found
[auth 57ee20c] style(Nav.tsx): adheres to eslint rules
1 file changed, 27 insertions(+), 6 deletions(-)
```

And the commit message cuts off. On GitHub, the line in question looks like this

```
line 92 and 122: add  in docstrings
```

### What I have tried

I have tried using three of the " ` " thingies and I have also tried using `<code></code>`
When I use "```", I get the same message and problem, and when I use `<code></code>`, the `command not found` error is gone, but the commit message retains the `<code></code>` blocks instead of converting it. I have also tried string escaping like this

```bash
line 92 and 122: add \`@returns\` in docstrings
```

And the like the code blocks, the commit message retains the " ` " instead of converting it.

Comment: It has nothing to do with git: it's the shell. Because you're using double quotes, the shell is taking the backticks to mean "execute this command substitution". That's why you see the "command not found" error. Use single quotes for your commit message.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Bash, double-quoted strings are subject to [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)*. That's what the backticks are doing in the first case, and why you're seeing `bash: @returns: command not found`. To fix it, you can escape them, like you did:

```
git commit -am "style(Nav.tsx): adheres to eslint rules

...
line 92 and 122: add \`@returns\` in docstrings"
```

or use single quotes:

```
git commit -am 'style(Nav.tsx): adheres to eslint rules

...
line 92 and 122: add `@returns` in docstrings'
```

But, the backticks will be retained. Commit messages are plain text. The fancy formatting in that screenshot is being done by GitHub, not git. I believe GitHub supports [Markdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) in commit messages. (Stack Exchange also uses Markdown.)

---

* BTW if you *did* want to do command substitution in Bash, you should use the new syntax, `$(command)` instead of `` `command` ``.

Comment: Ok thanks, that's what I wanted to know. One more thing; how come the backticks in my single line commit worked, but the multi-line commit didn't work?

Comment: @Luke-zhang-04 Hmm, I created a dummy repo just to check that but I couldn't reproduce the behaviour with the single-line or multi-line parts. I'm not sure, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

## What probably happened

Your shell (probably bash or some bourne shell variant) has a feature to execute commands and use the result to build a new command line. One of the ways to access that feature is by backticks. You can e.g. do

```
echo "Today is `date`."
```

to show the output of `date` within a nice little sentence.

## What you can do instead to have `` ` `` in your commit message

- Use single quotes (`'`) around the message argument. Bash and sh don't perform command substitution in single-quoted strings.

  or
- Compose the commit message in an editor, rather than passing it on the command line. Do so by omitting the `-m` option and its argument. Git will then open the editor specified by the environment variable `$EDITOR` to let you edit the commit message.

## Commit messages are plain text

To Git and its command line tools (e.g. `git log`), commit messages are plain text, without any markup language. Hosting platforms like GitHub and third-party tools may interpret that plain text as some markup language in some context, but not necessarily in all contexts. Wherever GitHub does that, it'll usually be interpreting it as GitHub flavored MarkDown.